# Ubuntu 14.04 kernel upgrades not changing default

Tags: 14.04, grub2, upgrade, kernel

So i have **3.13.0-34** & **3.13.0-33** & **3.13.0-24** all installed but the system constantly sticks with 3.13.0-24.

`update-grub` does not seem to change this. grub configuration says boot entry 0. I'm at a bit of a loss what to do next but want to keep my kernel updated when I do a `dist-upgrade`, currently it installs the newer kernel packages but never uses anything but 3.13.0-24.

The output of uname -a.

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The contents of /boot.

```
$ ls /boot
abi-3.13.0-24-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.13.0-33-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.13.0-34-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.13.0-24-generic      System.map-3.13.0-24-generic
config-3.13.0-33-generic      System.map-3.13.0-33-generic
config-3.13.0-34-generic      System.map-3.13.0-34-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-33-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
```

Here is the grub.cfg info requested.

```
$ grep Ubuntu /boot/grub/grub.cfg
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-34-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-34-generic-advanced-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-34-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-34-generic-recovery-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-33-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-33-generic-advanced-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-33-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-33-generic-recovery-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a' {
```

and the output of "sudo update-grub".

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin 
done
```

Comment: Can you confirm that all three versions are present in the output of `grep Ubuntu /boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Comment: Added requested output to the question because the comment mangled the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/512274/boot-ubuntu-with-latest-kernel-version): I solved this, just read [my comment here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/512274/boot-ubuntu-with-latest-kernel-version#comment693287_512274)

Comment: That's great. Unfortunately (for the purposes of diagnostics) that all looks normal. Two more ideas though. Are you *sure* you've done a proper reboot since installing those? A lot of people hibernate without thinking about it and some things (like the crashkernel setup) hotwire the reboot sequence so you never get back to grub. Do a proper shutdown, power off and start up. Failing that, what happens if you manually select the latest version at the grub screen (hold left shift while booting)?

Comment: @KasiyA - that looks like a workable tempoary fix however the next time "sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade" brings in a new kernel, won't I be stuck with my manual selection? In 12.04 when I dist-upgrade and a new kernel comes in it's set as the default boot selection.

Comment: @Oli - Yes, I have rebooted the server this morning just to be sure and several times before that.


`$ uptime`
`06:44:49 up 53 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.08, 0.09`

Comment: What about manual interactive selection?

Comment: What do you want? do you want to boot Ubuntu with last kernel or old kernel or your manual selection kernel?

Comment: Manual interactive selection is not an option because it's a VM hosted in the cloud and I don't have a remote console to access the machine during bootup.

I want the newest kernel to be selected as the default boot choice. When a newer kernel is installed during a "dist-upgrade" I want that to be set as the new default. The same behavior as 12.04 basically.

Comment: Try this post http://ariekanarie.nl/archives/211/remote-kernel-upgrade-with-debianubuntu-and-grub2 and used also [here](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2012/10/24/4584/)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the hosting company I use (Digital Ocean) have a control panel through their website that allows you to set the kernel. It also appears that their site does not in any way respect the OS choices made about which kernel the system will boot.

Resolved by choosing kernel through their control panel. This is only affecting my droplets on their service, not live local machines (tested and confirmed).

According to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-update-a-digitalocean-server-s-kernel this applies only to "old" droplets (I don't know **how** old :-)). That page also shows the steps to make those droplets respect the OS selected kernel.